# How does Yii timestamps work?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Yii says it can automatically set the timestamps 'created_at': http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html#using-timestampbehavior

However, every time I created a record, the time is blank:

```
$ yii kw/test
1437683634

mysql> select * from ad_group_keyword_network where ad_group_keyword_id = 1;
+---------------------+-
| created_at          | 
+---------------------+-
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
+---------------------+-

  public function actionTest() {
    $agkn = new AdGroupKeywordNetwork();
    $agkn->save();
    echo $agkn->created_at;
```

I tried with `Schema::TYPE_TIMESTAMP` and I changed the field and also tried with `Schema::TYPE_DATETIME`. They both return an integer timestamp in the field after save, but the time is all 0s in the database.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at'],
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => [],
```

Comment: yii timstamps are unix timestamps, and you're trying to stuff those integers in a mysql date field, which expects strings in the form of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. since your integer is NOT in that format, you get the all-zeroes date, which is "unknown/invalid" date.

Comment: @MarcB Ok. I expected Yii to convert based on the type of the field. It never mentions the required type. Guess it still has to catch up to Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `created_at` must be type INT (11) for the Yii 2 timestamp behaviour work. I think you are using type TIMESTAMP which will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what Marc and Michael said, I used this and it worked.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => null,
            'value' => function(){return date(DATE_ATOM);},
```

---

```
$ yii kw/test
2015-07-23T16:59:17-04:00
...
+---------------------+
| created_at          |
+---------------------+
| 2015-07-23 16:59:17 |
```

Answer (score 0):

**$value** is the expression that will be used for generating the timestamp, by default it will use the value of `time()` unless you assign to it an anonymous function that returns the timestamp value :

```
'timestamp' => [
    'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
    'attributes' => [
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'created_at',
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_at',
    ],
    'value' => function() { return date('U'); },
],
```

Or an yii\db\Expression object representing a DB expression :

```
'timestamp' => [
    'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
    'attributes' => [
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'created_at',
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_at',
    ],
    'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()'), // MySql exp
],
```